# Portfolio loss estimation using pairwise correlations

Tags: r, optimization, vectorization

im trying to estimate the portfolio losses using pairwise correlation matrix. The current code which runs fine using two 'for' loops to do the job and takes a fair amount of time. Is there any way to optimize the code to reduce the run time?
Corp here is the number of obligors or counterparties (1000 in this case)

Edit: Trying to explain the logic a little better here
So there is a data frame df that contains borrower details (Client_ID, Sector, Exposure, Probablity of default (PD) ). For example

Client ID is 1, 2, 3, 4,5 uptil 1000
Sector ID could be anything from 1 to 21
Exposure is any amount from 0 to 99999999

So i need to identify all client_ID pairs, multiply their exposures,  and here is where it gets complicates, i need to also multiply their correlation value . This correlation value is stored in  a separate 21*21 matrix, and is chosen on the basis of sectors to which the two clients belong. What is the most efficient way to do this? The code below does the stuff fine, but it takes a while, and i feel there must be an easier way to do this? merge? Expand.grid?

```
RC_UL=function(N_EAD, N_PD, N_LGD, N_LGD_VAR,N_CO_FAC_LOAD,V_SECTOR_ID,N_DFLT_PT)
{for (i in 1:corp){
for(j in 1:corp ){

if (i==j) { 
#borrower correlation with himself is always 1
sigma.ijk <- cbind( c(1, 1),c(1, 1)) 

} else
{ sigma.ijk <- cbind( c(1, N_CO_FAC_LOAD[i]*N_CO_FAC_LOAD[j] *rho[V_SECTOR_ID[i], V_SECTOR_ID[j]]),c(N_CO_FAC_LOAD[i]*N_CO_FAC_LOAD[j] * rho[V_SECTOR_ID[i], V_SECTOR_ID[j]], 1))
}
#rho is the correlation matrix across sectors (not shown in the code snippet #i have provided, but it is a 21*21 matrix corresponding to the 21 sectors #that the counterparties belong to
#N_CO_FAC_LOAD is an input that is specific to a sector      
#UL for each borrower  
UL[i]<-UL[i]+N_LGD[i] * N_LGD[j] *
N_EAD[i] * N_EAD[j] *
( pmvnorm(upper=c(N_DFLT_PT[i], N_DFLT_PT[j]), mean=c(0,0),sigma=sigma.ijk) - N_PD[i] * N_PD[j] )
}}
for (i in 1:corp){N_RC_UL[i]<-(UL[i]/sqrt(sum(UL)))}
return(N_RC_UL)
}

b<-RC_UL(EAD, PD, LGD, N_LGD_VAR,fac_weight_s,sector,def_pt1)
```